# Xamarin: How to debug Xamarin Android on Visual Studio

Tags: android, debugging, deployment, xamarin

I have a problem with debugging the android enabled device when coding with xamarin under Visual Studio. I can deploy the code and run it on the device but if I use the debug instead of deploy then I receive this message.

"Project not selected to build for this solution configuration"

Do I need to setup anything to debug the device.

Answer (score 3):

Are projects selected to build for the Debug configuration? Change the configuration to Debug, then go to Build > Configuration Manager menu in Visual Studio.  Are the project(s) checked under the "Build" column?

Comment: Yes it was being checked

Comment: @Simon You also have to tick the "Deploy" box in the Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a message such as:

"Project not selected to build for this solution configuration"

or

========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========

This typically indicates your deploy was skipped.

You need to go to Build -> Configuration Manager and check the respective Deploy checkbox for your Xamarin.Android project.